# How to get more then 100 results with PHP ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, selectize.js

I use a jQuery `selectize()` with ajax call.
The `selectize()` and the ajax call with PHP SELECT works fine.

The only problem is, ajax success callback is showing a max of 100 results.
When the PHP SELECT has more than 100 results the `selectize()` has no results.

Is there a way to use all of the results? `maxResults:` doesn't work here. :(

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible jsfiddle. I can't think of any limitation near 100.

Comment: Link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmh6rsdd/) here is the js function.